# .htaccess: Serve static files from public directory without public in URL, else rewrite to index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Bellow is my site directory structure:

```
htdocs/
    My-Project/
        .htaccess
        public/
            css/
            img/
                img.jpg
            js/
        index.php
        ...(other stuff)
```

I want to use an .htaccess file to check if the requested path is a file in the public/ directory *(similar to serving static files from an directory in express with express.static)*. If yes, serve it, else forward request to /index.php.

#### Basically my problem can be split into the following Sub-Problems:

SubProblem1: Serve **only files from public directory**, else route to index.php
SubProblem2: Serve these files from public directory **without (need of) 'public' in the URL**

So `/My-Project/img/img.jpg` should be rewritten to `/My-Project/public/img/img.jpg` but `/My-Project/notexisting.file` or `/My-Project/test`should be rewritten to  `/My-Project/index.php`.

This was my idea so far:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    
    #Block 1
    #Condition: File exists in public directory
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/My-Project/public/$1 -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

    #Block 2
    #Condition: File doesn't exist in public directory
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/My-Project/public/$1 !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

When `Block 1` stands alone -> SubProblem2 is solved, but as soon as `Block 2` is added for solving SubProblem1 every Request is rewritten to index.php. Why does that happen? **Why doesn't work the second RewriteCond as expected?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second RewriteCond didn't work as I expected, because as soon as Block1 rewrites the Request, $1 in Block2 doesn't contain the same Information as in Block1.

#### Example

Imagine we have the URI `/My-Project/img/img.jpg`. 
In **Block1** `$1` will be `img/img.jpg`. Because this file exists, the RewriteCondition would be fulfilled and the new URI will be `My-Project/public/img/img.jpg`. 
Now it comes to **Block2**: Because of the rewritten URI, `$1` is here defined as `public/img/img.jpg`. So the RewriteCondition will check, if there is any existing File under the URL `MyProject/public/public/img/img.jpg`. Of course it isn't. So the RewriteCondition will always be fulfilled and every Request will be rewritten to index.php regardless of any former Rewriting.

#### Solution

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/My-Project/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/My-Project/public/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond $1 !^public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use:

```
RewriteEngine On

# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]


# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

> Update My apache vhost configuration if you need it looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName awesome.scot
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            FallbackResource /index.php
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride FileInfo All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php)$ fcgi://php:9000/var/www/html/public/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Then in `/etc/hosts`, I added `127.0.0.1 awesome.scot`, so now I access my site in the browser with `http://awesome.scot`

Note the two folders in the vhost conf, one is the site root, one is the public directory.

If you haven't turned vhosts on, give it a try! Uncomment the vhosts line in your apache conf, then go into the extra folder and configure your vhost, then restart!

Comment: But this solution serves any existing file, but I want only existing files in public directory :/

Comment: this htaccess goes IN the public directory. That's where mine is and it only serves from within public

Comment: but is your index.php either in the public directory?

Comment: Yes, look here https://github.com/delboy1978uk/bonemvc/tree/master/public

Comment: that's not what I want, I want to have the index.php in the root directory

Comment: oh, that's a strange setup. Can I ask why?

Comment: i guess you can just tweak it and add the public folder something like `RewriteCond %public/{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]` ? Not sure though

Comment: maybe it's kind of dumb to achieve what I want :D, but I do it because I do not want '… .php' in my URLs, so index.php ist doing all my further Routing. As soon as index.php is in my Public directory, it is accessible by /My-Project/index.php

Comment: none of my urls have `.php` in them either. It all goes through the index.php where a routing component figures out what to do next

Comment: if you set up vhosts, you can point to `public/index.php` by default when you type in whatever fake domain you define in the vhost. Well worth the 5 minutes to set up! Then you just visit `http://my-fake-domain.com` to get your home page. This is also far closer to a production setup and so I thoroughly recommend trying this out!

Comment: In my `public/index.php`, I set an `APPLICATION_PATH` env var to one level down, ie where your index.php is, so any calls to php files or anything will start from the site root https://github.com/delboy1978uk/bonemvc/blob/master/public/index.php#L38-L41